# Edge services discovery

Tags: rest, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am POCing a Spring Cloud based implementation.  I have a Eureka registry with a Node based edge service.  The Node service uses a Prana side car to resolve registered services on Eureka as well as register the Node service.  What is the best practice for resolving the edge service? I read about Zuul.  Is that the right approach? Or should it be hosted on a gateway like WSO2? Also, if the edge services are a cluster then what is the system layout that is commonly used?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your actual needs. I recommend using Zuul on your edge if you need a lot of control over your routing, loadbalance, filter logic etc or you are running your own stack and/or you don't have access to dynamic loadbalancers.

We are currently running multiple Zuul instances on AWS behind ELB, they are invoked in a round robin fashion and the requests are routed to the appropriate service based on numerous factors (metadata, path, variables). We haven't had any issues with performance so far.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  If I am thinking correctly, Zuul would function just like Haproxy.  Any advantages or disadvantage?  Did you consider Haproxy?

Comment: We didn't consider Haproxy since Zuul plugs in to the existing spring-cloud architecture and it works out of the box, instantly load balancing between services registered in eureka. It was the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Did you investigate a dedicated gateway such as WSO2, Apigee etc? And looks like you have implemented without one.  Any insights as to limitations of Zuul vs Api-Gateway.  Obviously, one cant load balance with a gateway (to my knowledge).

Comment: I haven't looked into Api-Gateway (AWS) so fat but I know that with Zuul you gain extensibility and configuration over almost anything since it was written in java and already uses one of the most powerful frameworks so there is very little you can't solve with it.